# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined react

Tags: reactjs

I have an array object called products which I am looping over and passing the array as props into the Product component.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Grid} from '@material-ui/core';
import Product from './Product/Product'

const Products = () => {

  const products = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Shoes', description: 'running shoes', price: 1.5},
    {id: 2, name: 'Macbook', description: 'Apple macbook', price: 1.5}
  ]
  return(

  <main>
    <Grid container justify='center' spacing={1}>
      {products.map((product) => {
        <Grid item key={product.id} xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
          <Product product={product}/>
        </Grid>
      })}
    </Grid>
  </main>
) 
}

export default Products
```

I am trying to destructure the product array in the product,jsx file and call product.name however this is showing as the type error

```
 as TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined react



import React from 'react'
import {Card, CardMedia, CardContent, CardActions, Typography, IconButton, Icon} from '@material-ui/core';
import {AddShoppingCart} from '@material-ui/icons'
import useStyles from './styles'; 

const Product = ({product}) => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  return ( 
    <div>
      <Card className={classes.root}>
        <CardMedia className={classes.media} image='' title={product.name}/>
        <CardContent>
          <div className={classes.CardContent}>
            <Typography variant='h5 gutterbottom'>
              {product.price}
            </Typography>

            <Typography variant='h5'>
              {product.name}
            </Typography>

          </div>
          <Typography variant='h2' color='textSecondary'>{product.description}</Typography>
        </CardContent>
        <CardActions disableSpacing className={classes.CardActions}>
          <IconButton aria-label='Add to Cart'>
          <AddShoppingCart/>
          </IconButton>
        </CardActions>
      </Card>
      
    </div>
  )
}



export default Product
```

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) license, for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Comment: `const Product = ({product}) => { if(!product) return 'falsy product!'`

Answer (score 0):

Try to destructure like this.

```
 [...products].map((product) => {
    <Grid item key={product.id} xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
      <Product product={product}/>
    </Gri
```

Answer (score 0):

On returning you should not use multiline:
you can do this two way:

```
{products.map((product) => {
        return <Grid item key={product.id} xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
          <Product product={product}/>
        </Grid>
      })}
```

or

```
{products.map((product) => <Grid item key={product.id} xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}> 
      <Product product={product}/>
        </Grid>
 )}
```